# Form tag is not being rendered on clients browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, forms

Well, I'm an expert myself, but couldn't find any possible reason for this behavior. I'm running WIN2K8 R2 with ASP.NET 4.0 for about a year. My website has been up and running, with no changes at all. Yesterday, I've been receiving complaints about the website's login which is not visible.

My website is div-based, and has all div placed as layers (with z-indexes). The login wrapper is a simple div which contains a form tag (runat=server).

I successfully restored the case - just entered my website and BOOM - the login div is missing. Tried to mess with it on the developer tools (using chrome) but no luck. Just hit F5 and it was back again, and never occurred again. It happened on Firefox, chrome and IE8 both on the same minute - but after a F5 hit and was resolved for good.

This div is the only div that is invisible to some clients. Other divs, which use the same z-index, are displayed. I've tried to disable GZip, disable Google Analytics and other 3rd party css/js that are loaded, but no luck.

Strange thing is that the problem is solved once hitting F5. Like is has something to do with Cache, yet I explicitly set no-cache header.

Any experts to guess what is going on?
the only changes on the server were windows updates

UPDATE: just found out that the conduit app engine is doing this!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I would look at the request with firebug and confirm that indeed the issue is not caching because that's what it looks like. I wouldn't just blindly trust the fact that you set the no-cache header.

Comment: Could it be you are running some jquery, and it gets executed before the page has loaded ? Second time, everything is loaded and so the script runs. If so make sure you wrap you jQuery code in `$(function(){/*your jquery code here..*/});`

Comment: Just checked, there is no cache at all. Response Headers:
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:5655
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:30:48 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
p3p:CP="NID DSP ALL COR"

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. Run your page through an HTML validator. Strange errors like that sometimes are caused by malformed HTML.
2. Try to capture the HTML of the page - it's possible something on the server is rendering it differently, perhaps it's missing a cookie that exists on the second run, perhaps it needs to load a cache - it's impossible for me to say.
3. Check for hacks, they sometimes insert code that does who knows what.

Comment: Thanks. It validates just fine, no hacks are found. The HTML output is fine, no broken tags or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to locate that DIV via Firebug/Dev tools in chrome while is hidden. Could you examine its CSS?

Is there any script generating/injecting HTML code?

Comment: Yes, I can see the div. Tried to edit its style, but no luck. Only when I deleted it and re-inserted it - it was back. No injections.

Comment: So what are its properties? When you select it, is it also hilited on page? Is it overlapped by something? Are there any overrided CSS properties? Is there display property set?